# RealmObject always reads property as false in code

Tags: xamarin.forms, realm

Weird error. I have a RealmObject

```
public class Course : RealmObject
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsFavorite { get; set; }

    private static readonly ImageSource IsFavoriteImage = ImageSource.FromFile("starYellow");
    private static readonly ImageSource IsNotFavoriteImage = ImageSource.FromFile("starGray");
    public ImageSource FavoriteButtonImage => IsFavorite ? IsFavoriteImage : IsNotFavoriteImage;

}
```

Data bound to a list, works fine. Shows a yellow or gray star, depending whether the Course is favorited or not. When I click the star, I fire off a `Command` that ends up in this function:

```
public void ToggleFavorite(int courseId)
{
    var course = _realm.Find<Data.Course>(courseId);
    if (course != null)
    {
        _realm.Write(() =>
        {
            course.IsFavorite = !course.IsFavorite;
        });
    }
}
```

Now, here's the weird part. No matter what I do, `IsFavorite` is always read as `false`. Setting it explicitly to `true` and it still reads as `false`. I've tired to expand the code with an if and setting it to true or false. Didn't work.

If I use the debugger to view the object, I can see that it in some cases is true (when a course is marked as a favorite in the backend), but using the property in code is always false.

[image: Variable is true and false at the same time]

If I set it to `true`, immediately afterwards, it's still false.
[image]

Anyone have a similar problem?

Comment: Can you send us a repro project so we can investigate (help@realm.io)? That's not something we have come across in our tests.

Comment: I never found a solution to this and ended up removing Realm from the project since it started to block me with some exceptions I couldn't find the cause of when instantiating Realm. Will look back at it in my next project.

Answer (score -1):

Work for me

```
public void ToggleFavorite(int courseId)
{
    var course = _realm.Find<Data.Course>(courseId);
    if (course != nu`enter code here`ll)
    {
        _realm.Write(() =>
        {
            course.IsFavorite = !course.IsFavorite;
        });
    }

    //Get object again after update.
    course = _realm.Find<Data.Course>(courseId);
}
```

Comment: I believe the real uses an isolated transaction and an update of the object isn't returned a new state for a local variable